# Integrate oracle reports 12c with oracle forms 12c running using FSAL running feature

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, oracleforms, oraclereports

I using oracle forms and reports 12c running on a weblogic sever 12c.
I can call a report when running a form on the web using java applet option, but when
I run the form using FSAL option
an error is raising frm-41214 unable to run report
the source code of a button on the form when-button-pressed as below
declare
      xpath           varchar2(45);

```
  PARALIST        paramlist;

  rep_id               report_object;

  v_rep               varchar2(100);

  v_report_server varchar2(100);

  v_servlet_url   varchar2(500);

  v_job_id        varchar2(100);

  rep_status      varchar2(100);

  P_FILE_NAME     varchar2(100);

begin  

P_FILE_NAME:='C:\erp\'||'attendencelist.PDF';

  xpath:='C:\erp\HR\AttendenceList.rdf';

 PARALIST := Get_Parameter_List('param_list_main');

IF id_null(paralist) THEN

   PARALIST := CREATE_PARAMETER_LIST('param_list_main');

ELSE

   Destroy_Parameter_List(paralist);

   PARALIST := CREATE_PARAMETER_LIST('param_list_main');

END IF;

ADD_PARAMETER(PARALIST,'month',TEXT_PARAMETER,:block3.month);

ADD_PARAMETER(PARALIST,'year1',TEXT_PARAMETER,:block3.year1);

   v_report_server := 'rep_wls_reports_sanjay';

v_servlet_url   := 'sanjay:9002/reports/rwservlet';

  rep_id:=find_report_object('Report5');

  set_report_object_property(rep_id,REPORT_SERVER,v_report_server);

set_report_object_property(rep_id,REPORT_EXECUTION_MODE,BATCH);

set_report_object_property(rep_id,REPORT_COMM_MODE,SYNCHRONOUS);

set_report_object_property(rep_id,REPORT_DESTYPE,FILE);

set_report_object_property(rep_id,REPORT_DESFORMAT,'PDF');

set_report_object_property(rep_id,REPORT_FILENAME,xpath);      

set_report_object_property(rep_id,REPORT_DESNAME,P_FILE_NAME); 

v_rep:=run_report_object(rep_id,PARALIST);

rep_status := REPORT_OBJECT_STATUS(v_rep);

 V_JOB_ID := SUBSTR(V_REP,INSTR(V_REP,'_',-1)+1);

IF rep_status = 'FINISHED' THEN

      web.show_document('http://'||v_servlet_url||'/getjobid'||V_JOB_ID,'_blank');

END IF;   


exception when no_data_found then

 null;

end;
```

please is there any way to solve this problem or FSAL option does not support integration with oracle report?!!

Answer (score 0):

FRM-41214 indicates that an invalid parameter has been passed to the report server. And the [release notes](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/forms/documentation/oracleforms-12210-newfeatures-2906037.pdf) when FSAL came out indicates that:

> Because FSAL runs the application without a browser, features that are browser dependent are not supported in this mode.  These will include Java Script, Single sign-off, and Single sign-on.

So either your user is not authenticated when you attempt to run the report from FSAL, or you are missing a parameter that Forms is auto-populating for you in the Java Applet that is not populated when running from FSAL.